# Using a Join to show only records with no matching foreign key

Tags: sql-server

I have been working at this all day, trying multiple suggestions from multiple sites and I just can't seem to figure this out!

I am using MS SQL and I have 3 SQL tables that have the following columns:

```
USERS
------
UserID

UserAccounts
------------
UserID
AccountID

Accounts
--------
AccountID
```

Here is a [diagram of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZO5C3.png) (ignore the data types, just for relationship reference)

I need to retrieve a list of accounts where a given UserID from the Users table does not have an entry in the UserAccounts table.

The problem I am running into is that many users can be associated with many of the same accounts. So for example, in the table UserAccounts this data would be valid:

```
UserAccounts
------------------
|UserID|AccountID|
------------------
| 1    | 1       |
| 2    | 1       |
| 2    | 3       |
```

Because of this, I can't use the "IS NULL" test and filtering out by a given username won't work using "<> @UserID" since user 2 isn't the same as user 1 it still returns that row.

Does this make any sense? I am literally at my wits end!

**edit:**
I changed my query to:

```
SELECT        Accounts.ID, Accounts.CompanyAgencyName
FROM            Accounts LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        UserID, AccountID
                               FROM            MyAccount.UserAccounts
                               WHERE        (UserID = @UserID)) AS DerivedUserAccounts ON Accounts.ID = DerivedUserAccounts.AccountID
WHERE        (DerivedUserAccounts.AccountID IS NULL)
ORDER BY Accounts.ID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User Table with values { 1,2,3,4,5 }

Account table with values { 10,20,30,40,50 }

UserAccount table with values { {1,20},{1,50},{2,20},{3,10},{4,40},{4,50} }

Query:

```
declare @userId int; set @userId = 4;
with cte ( userId, accountId ) as
(
select userId, accountId from userAccount where userId = @userId
)
select a.*
from
    account a
    left join cte b on ( a.Id = b.accountId )
where
    ( b.accountId is null )
```

Results:

10,20,30

Comment: I had to alter the query a little to work in my project, but this worked perfectly!
`SELECT        Accounts.ID, Accounts.CompanyAgencyName
FROM            Accounts LEFT OUTER JOIN
                             (SELECT        UserID, AccountID
                               FROM            MyAccount.UserAccounts
                               WHERE        (UserID = @UserID)) AS DerivedUserAccounts ON Accounts.ID = DerivedUserAccounts.AccountID
WHERE        (DerivedUserAccounts.AccountID IS NULL)
ORDER BY Accounts.ID`

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from accounts a where not exists (select * from UserAccounts where AccountID=a.AccountID and UserID=738)
```

where 738 is the given UserID.

Comment: This probably works, but I was trying to avoid using the _not exists_ for performance reasons. I've read in the multiple searches that I've done on this that doing that can cause performance issues in large tables. Thinking ahead...I decided to use the _join_ option instead.

Comment: @ZacharyWeber The optimizer sorts such issues out - the execution plan at the end will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Or in a more general form

```
create table #user (uid int primary key);
create table #account (aid int primary key);
create table #useraccount (uauid int,uaaid int PRIMARY KEY (uauid,uaaid));
insert into #user VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
insert into #account VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
insert into #useraccount VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(2,3);
SELECT * FROM #user WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #useraccount WHERE uauid=uid)
```

see [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/414411/find-users-without-account). I have left out the second join from `useraccount` to `account`. The complete select should actually be:

```
SELECT * FROM #user WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM #useraccount JOIN #account ON aid=uaaid WHERE uauid=uid)
```

Comment: The query doesn't work for what I was looking for.
If the tables contain the data you use in your example and the @UserID parameter is "1" then the output result should be {2,3,4} instead of {3,4} since user "1" doesn't have a record in #useraccount for accounts with the id 2, 3 or 4.